# Fixing an integrator

Tags: python, out-of-memory, differential-equations, integrator

I'm trying to solve a system of differential equations using Python. I've written an algorithm that uses Euler's Method to do so, and I require a time step of 10^-6 s-1, for 100s. That is 10^8 data points, and the computer returns a MemoryError.

The code I have is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

k1 = 1.34
k2 = 1.6E+9
k3 = 8E+3
k4 = 4E+7
k5 = 1

def f_A(A,Y):
    return -k1*A*Y

def f_B(B,X):
    return -k3*X*B

def f_X(X,Y,A,B):
    return k1*A*Y - k2*X*Y + k3*B*X - k4*X*X 

def f_Y(X,Y,Z,A):
    return -k1*A*Y - k2*X*Y + k5*Z

def f_Z(X,Z,B):
    return -k5*Z + k3*B*X

def f_P(X,Y,A):
    return k1*A*Y + k2*X*Y

def f_Q(X):
    return k4*X*X

def Euler(fA,fB,fX,fY,fZ,fP,fQ,t0,tt,n):
    h = (tt - t0) / float(n)

    t = [0]*(n)
    X = [0]*(n)
    Y = [0]*(n)
    Z = [0]*(n)
    P = [0]*(n)
    Q = [0]*(n)
    A = [0]*(n)
    B = [0]*(n)

    t[0] = t0
    X[0] = 10**-9.8
    Y[0] = 10**-6.52
    Z[0] = 10**-7.32
    A[0] = 0.06
    B[0] = 0.06
    P[0] = 0
    Q[0] = 0

    for i in range(1,n):

        t[i] = t0 + i*h

        X[i] = X[i-1] + h*fX(X[i-1],Y[i-1],A[i-1],B[i-1])

        Y[i] = Y[i-1] + h*fY(X[i-1],Y[i-1], Z[i-1], A[i-1])

        Z[i] = Z[i-1] + h*fZ(X[i-1],Z[i-1],B[i-1])

        A[i] = A[i-1] + h*fA(A[i-1],Y[i-1])

        B[i] = B[i-1] + h*fB(B[i-1],X[i-1])

        P[i] = P[i-1] + h*fP(X[i-1],Y[i-1],A[i-1])

        Q[i] = Q[i-1] + h*fQ(X[i-1])

    t_new = t[0::100]
    X_new = X[0::100]
    Y_new = Y[0::100]
    Z_new = Z[0::100]


    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.plot(t_new, X_new, label = 'X')
    plt.plot(t_new, Y_new, label = 'Y')
    plt.plot(t_new, Z_new, label = 'Z')
    plt.xlabel('time / s')
    plt.ylabel('concentration')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

t_0 = 0
t_t = 100 
m = 10**8

Euler(f_A,f_B,f_X,f_Y,f_Z,f_P,f_Q,t_0,t_t,m)
```

The _new lists are used to help plotting, so as to avoid overloading Matplotlib. Does anyone have any advice on how I can avoid the memory error while still maintaining the required time-step?

PS as part of the project, it is required that I write my own integrator.

Comment: Do you really need to plot 10^8 data points? Trying to allocate memory for lists with 10^8 elements is probably what causes the error.

Comment: test without plotting, and for the purpose of visualisation do some averaging

Comment: Unless you are doing this for the sake of the exercise or you really know what you are doing, please do not use Euler integrators or program integrators yourself. That wheel [has already been invented](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html#solving-initial-value-problems-for-ode-systems).

Comment: This is indeed for the sake of exercise sadly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not trying to keep every iteration of every variable at each time step in memory. You should simply have a 'current' and 'next' version of each variable, update them each time step, and then 'save' the state every 1,000,000 time steps or so. Try something like this:

```
def Euler(fA,fB,fX,fY,fZ,fP,fQ,t0,tt,n):
    num_samples = 100

    h = (tt - t0) / float(n)

    # initialise variables
    t = t0
    X = 10**-9.8
    ...

    # initialise _samples lists
    t_samples = []
    X_samples = []
    Y_samples = []
    Z_samples = []

    for i in range(1,n):
        # save the state once every (n / num_samples) time steps
        if i % (n / num_samples) == 0:
            t_samples.append(t)
            X_samples.append(X)
            Y_samples.append(Y)
            Z_samples.append(Z)

        # compute the next version of each variable
        t_ = t0 + i*h
        X_ = X + h*fX(X, Y, A, B)
        ...

        # update the variables
        t, X, Y, Z, A, B, P, Q = t_, X_, Y_, Z_, A_, B_, P_, Q_

    # plot using _samples lists
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 8 arrays of size 10^8.  If each entry in the array is a byte then this amounts to 100 MB per array.  Even if you tried to write this out to a file it would be a pretty big file.

I would suggest you have to reduce the amount of data points.